# Why hex address addition are not the same in gdb and python

Tags: python, gdb

I'm doing a buffer overflow exercice with gdb and python(3.9) pwntools on kali.
I'm working with a 32bits ELF so my context is set this way :
`context(arch="i386", os="linux")`

I'm at the step I have to calculate offset between addresses functions and the result in python is driving me crazy.

**In gdb** : p 0xf7e280e0 + 0xefdc8000 = 0xe7bf00e0

**In my python script** : 0xf7e280e0 + 0xefdc8000 = 0x**1**e7bf00e0

Can you help me to understand why the result is not the same?

Thanks :)

Comment: Python ints are not limited to 4 bytes.

Comment: Thanks @khelwood for your feedback. Is there any way to force this ?

Comment: Force what to do what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you help me to understand why the result is not the same?

Python performs arithmetic with arbitrary precision. If you add two 32-bit numbers, the result could overflow and produce a number which does not fit in 32 bits.

> Is there any way to force this?

Assuming by "force this" you mean: force Python to compute a 32-bit number, sure: you just need to mask off the bits you don't want:

```
result = result & 0xFFFFFFFF
```